# use of "rmdir" command with batch file

Tags: batch-file, rmdir

I don't have exact directory path rather its absolute in terms of current working directory.
whenever I am using this path, it prompts to ask wether its a directory or file, how to suppress this prompt.

```
rmdir "..\Sample\special" /s/q
```

Comment: are you sure this is the command that produces the prompt. Is there usage of `xcopy` ?

Comment: yeah right this problem is from xcopy  :) do have any idea how to overcome.

Comment: show more of your code.Usual approach is to use `echo f|xcopy ..` if you are trying to copy a file or better to use `copy` command

Comment: actually i am trying to copy a directory?

Comment: okay got it i have to use echo d|xcopy, right :)  thanks buddy.